# Iterate through objects and output to json array in jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to iterate through a list of objects and then output to a JSON array. I can't figure out how to crack this one. I am scraping data using cheerio with node if that helps any.

My current output is:

```
[
    {
        "gold_bid": "1204.50",
        "gold_ask": "1205.50",
        "gold_change": "+3.70",
        "gold_percent": "+0.31%",
        "silver": "",
        "palladium": "",
        "platinum": ""
    },
    {
        "gold_bid": "1204.50",
        "gold_ask": "1205.50",
        "gold_change": "+3.70",
        "gold_percent": "+0.31%",
        "silver": "",
        "palladium": "",
        "platinum": ""
    },
    {
        "gold_bid": "1204.50",
        "gold_ask": "1205.50",
        "gold_change": "+3.70",
        "gold_percent": "+0.31%",
        "silver": "",
        "palladium": "",
        "platinum": ""
    }
]
```

The output I am looking to achieve:

```
[
    {
        "gold_bid": "1204.50",
        "gold_ask": "1205.50",
        "gold_change": "+3.70",
        "gold_percent": "+0.31%"
    },
    {
        "silver_bid": "704.50",
        "silver_ask": "805.50",
        "silver_change": "+1.70",
        "silver_percent": "+0.21%"
    },
    {
        "palladium_bid": "204.04",
        "palladium_ask": "555.30",
        "palladium_change": "+1.10",
        "palladium_percent": "+1.05%"
    }
]
```

jQuery:

```
var $ = cheerio.load(html);

      var gold_bid, gold_ask, gold_change, gold_percent, silver, palladium, platinum;
      var result = [];
      var json = { gold_bid : "", gold_ask: "",  gold_change: "", gold_percent: "",  silver : "", palladium : "", platinum: ""};


      $('.spot_price').filter(function(){
        var data = $(this);
        gold_bid = data.find('tr').eq(1).find('td').eq(3).text()
        gold_ask = data.find('tr').eq(1).find('td').eq(4).text()
        gold_change = data.find('tr').eq(1).find('td').eq(5).find('p').text()
        gold_percent = data.find('tr').eq(1).find('td').eq(6).find('p').text()

        json.gold_bid = gold_bid;
        json.gold_ask = gold_ask;
        json.gold_change = gold_change;
        json.gold_percent = gold_percent;

        silver_bid = data.find('tr').eq(2).find('td').eq(3).text()
        silver_ask = data.find('tr').eq(2).find('td').eq(4).text()
        silver_change = data.find('tr').eq(2).find('td').eq(5).find('p').text()
        silver_percent = data.find('tr').eq(2).find('td').eq(6).find('p').text()

        json.silver_bid = silver_bid;
        json.silver_ask = silver_ask;
        json.silver_change = silver_change;
        json.silver_percent = silver_percent;


      })

      for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
         result.push(json);
      }

    }

    fs.writeFile('data.json', JSON.stringify(result, null, 4), function(err){
    })
```

Any help would be solid this has been driving me mental.

***Update the output I am looking to achieve would not have the same values...Silver bid, ask, change would be different values...**

Comment: You are currently overwriting the same variable, `json`, several times, or as many times as there are `.spot_price` matches. The value of `json` will be determined by whatever the last `.spot_price` match is. You then push that same object to an array three times.

Comment: Thanks @DavidHedlund - Any suggestions on what to write to fix it?

Comment: It's not really clear what your input is, and I don't know why you want the output to say `silver_bid: 1204.50`, when you're always just setting `gold_bid`, etc. I don't really know where to start with this code. But you're currently using `filter` for something entirely different than filtering. May I suggest that you change `filter` to `map`, and return a new object in each iteration. `var result = $('.spot_price').map(function() { var item = {}; item.gold_bid = 123; return item; }).toArray()`

Comment: Sorry, the output I am looking to achieve would not have the same values...Silver bid, ask, change would be different values...

Comment: Yes, well regardless of the values, you're never setting a `silver_bid` and yet you expect one in your desired output. And you are starting with an object with a `silver` property, which you never use, and you don't want it in your output.

Comment: Hey there David, I'll update the code with the silver bid. I left that part out since it would be similar to gold

Comment: It's still not quite clear what's going on. Can you post an example of what the html might look like as well? How many instances of `.spot_price` are there?

Comment: I got it sorted. I had to rewire some things since it was not a typical json output...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest something like this:

```
$('.spot_price').each(function(index, element) {
  if (gold) { // use your condition here
    var json = { gold_bid : "", gold_ask: "", gold_change: "", gold_percent: ""};
    gold_bid = data.find('tr').eq(1).find('td').eq(3).text();
    gold_ask = data.find('tr').eq(1).find('td').eq(4).text();
    gold_change = data.find('tr').eq(1).find('td').eq(5).find('p').text();
    gold_percent = data.find('tr').eq(1).find('td').eq(6).find('p').text();
    json.gold_bid = gold_bid;
    json.gold_ask = gold_ask;
    json.gold_change = gold_change;
    json.gold_percent = gold_percent;
    result.push(json);
  } else if (silver) { // use your condition here
    ... 
  } else if (platinum) { // use your condition here
    ... 
  } 
});
```

The code assumes that a `.spot_price`-DOM-object contains information about gold, silver or platinum (exactly one of them).

Comment: I have no way to consistently distinguish so this wont work unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

```
var $ = cheerio.load(html);

var gold_bid, gold_ask, gold_change, gold_percent, silver, palladium, platinum;
var result = [];
var json = { gold : "", silver : "", palladium : "", platinum: ""};


$('.spot_price').filter(function(){
    var data = $(this);
    gold_bid = data.find('tr').eq(1).find('td').eq(3).text()
    gold_ask = data.find('tr').eq(1).find('td').eq(4).text()
    gold_change = data.find('tr').eq(1).find('td').eq(5).find('p').text()
    gold_percent = data.find('tr').eq(1).find('td').eq(6).find('p').text()

    $.each(json,function(k,v){
     var innerjson={}; 
      innerjson[k+"_bid"]=gold_bid;
      innerjson[k+"_ask"]=gold_ask;
      innerjson[k+"_change]=gold_change;
      innerjson[k+"_percent"]=gold_percent;
      result.push(innerjson);

    });

});

fs.writeFile('data.json', JSON.stringify(result, null, 4), function(err){})
```

I Guess this will work for ur scenario